# Computing the turbulent flame length

Tags: equilibrium, combustion

There is a problem I found online for practice that I cannot solve:

**Problem**

> Methane, $\ce{CH4}$, emerges from a $1\ \mathrm{cm}$ diameter nozzle
>   at a rate of $120\ \mathrm{cm^3/s}$ and a mole fraction of $0.04$, and burns as a turbulent flame. The laminar flame speed of methane is $45\ \mathrm{cm/s}$ and the turbulent intensity is measured as $v_\mathrm{rms}=2\ \mathrm{m/s}$. Given the correlation for the turbulent flame speed $$S_\mathrm t = 0.35 S_\mathrm L\left(\frac{v'_\mathrm{rms}}{S_\mathrm L}\right)^{0.7}$$
>   estimate the length of the flame. Assume that the flame is conical in shape

**What I've tried**

1. Compute the turbulent flame speed $S_\mathrm t=4.47\ \mathrm{m/s}$
2. From mass conservation, the mass flow rate exiting the pipe equal to the mass flow rate going through the flame. But there are still two unknowns before we can compute the area of the cone: the density of unburnt mixture and of the flame.
3. Assume $p=1\ \mathrm{atm}$ and $T=300\ \mathrm K$, compute density at the pipe exit using the Ideal gas Law $\rho = 1.15\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$
4. Compute the adiabatic flame temperature at those conditions $T_\mathrm{ad}\approx1050\ \mathrm K$ (using $C_p$ at $300\ \mathrm K$)
5. Compute the resulting density at the flame $\rho_\mathrm f=0.323\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$.
6. Compute the area of the cone and then the height of the cone

This method yield to the computation of the negative square root. What am I doing wrong? Even if there is a better way to approach this problem, I feel like my method should still give good results.

Comment: (1) think temperature is red herring (2) phrase *"and the turbulent intensity is 0 measured as v rms = 2m/s."* seems wrong.

Comment: @MaxW (2) was a typo but what about (1)? Problem does not mention temperature, that's just what I came up with.

Comment: I'd assume that flow out from nozzle was a stack of thin discs. So the cone is from a number of stacked discs. Each disc travels away from nozzle at 45 cm/s. Turbulent flow is due to oxygen diffusing from sides of disc which happens at 4.47 m/s. So it takes so time for oxygen to diffuse into center of disc.